# What query can I use to distinguish Cloud SQL from Postgresql?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there a simple query that will let me distinguish Cloud SQL from stock PostgreSQL?  Maybe something like `select version()` or `select current_setting('server_version')`?

(I don't have access to a Cloud SQL instance to experiment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, [things are the same](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#differences-pg). You could try looking for the CLOUDSQLSUPERUSER role, which wouldn't existing on regular postgres (unless you or someone else has added it).

EDIT: added @enocom's suggestions for a query to do this:
`select * from pg_catalog.pg_user where usename = 'cloudsqlsuperuser';`

Comment: A query to check for the cloudsqlsuperuser looks like this: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_user where usename = 'cloudsqlsuperuser';`.